# Symbol for a function from a group to itself

Tags: group-theory

Is there a symbol for the function that, given a normal subgroup H of G, associates to $g\in G$ the element $g'=gh^{-1}$ with $h\in H$?

EDIT

I reformulate the question: given a subgroup $H$ of a group $G$, under what hypotheses is it possible to define a $\mathrm{mod}$ like function of $G$ in itself?

For $\mathrm{mod}$ I mean the modulo operation, i.e. $\mathrm{mod}\colon \mathbb{Z}\mapsto\mathbb{Z}$ such that, given a modulus, a integer is associated with the remainder of the division of the integer by the modulus.
If such a function can exist, how is it indicated? Will I write $g\, \mathrm{mod}\,h$ or is there another symbol?

Comment: This is not well defined, unless $H$ is the trivial subgroup (in which case, your function is the identity). In every other situation, there are multiple possible values for $h$, and hence multiple possible values for $g’$, and hence not a function at all.

Comment: Ok! I've reformulated the question.

Answer (score 0):

As a *function* you could call it $t_{h^{-1}}$, meaning $t$ranslation by $h^{-1}$. Buuuut the fact that $h$ is in a normal subgroup is irrelevant, and this isn't a group *homomorphism*.

Comment: Ok! I've reformulated the question.